# Marker Detection with Area Learning

Tags: augmented-reality, google-project-tango

I want to use Marker Detection after detecting an area with Area Learning, but I can't find a way to do this. I have tried to merge the Google Tango SDK examples provided for Marker Detection and Area Learning but after localizing the area, it doesn't find the Marker Images provided by them. Is there a way to solve this "Marker Detection - Area Learning" issue, or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Unity SDK? I have merged them and it works without loading ADF [new area learning mode]. Make sure to enable video overlay [Texture and raw bytes] and register for the event.

VideoOverlayListener.RegisterOnTangoImageAvailable(this.OnTangoImageAvailableEventHandler);